# Unable to read the copied database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have used the below DBHelper class to copy the `sqlite` db from *assets* to sdcard.

**It copies the database perfectly on emulator and other android devices too but when I try to access the db through the app from any android device then the application crashes while on emulator it works fine.**

*`DBHelper.java`:-*

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteDatabase database = null;
public File databaseFile;
public static String databaseName = "Db1.sqlite";
public String databasePath = "";

Context mContext;

public DBHelper(Context paramContext) {

    super(paramContext, databaseName, null, 1);
    this.mContext = paramContext;

    this.databasePath =  (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/"+databaseName);
    this.databaseFile = new File(this.databasePath);
    if (!this.databaseFile.exists())
        try {
            deployDataBase(DBHelper.databaseName, this.databasePath);
            return;
        } catch (IOException localIOException) {
            localIOException.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private void deployDataBase(String dbNAme, String dbPath)
        throws IOException {
    InputStream localInputStream = this.mContext.getAssets().open(dbNAme);
    FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbPath);
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        int i = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte);
        if (i <= 0) {
            localFileOutputStream.flush();
            localFileOutputStream.close();
            localInputStream.close();
            return;
        }
        localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (database != null)
        database.close();

    super.close();

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

} 


public List<String> getAllColleges(){
    List<String> colleges = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM colleges_list";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            colleges.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning colleges
    return colleges;
}
```

*`LogCat`for devices other than emulator*:-

```
08-20 18:14:43.359: E/AndroidRuntime(24460): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 18:14:43.359: E/AndroidRuntime(24460): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sqlite/com.crm.Quote_Details}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: colleges_list: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM colleges_list
08-20 18:14:43.359: E/AndroidRuntime(24460):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 18:14:43.359: E/AndroidRuntime(24460): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: colleges_list: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM colleges_list
08-20 18:14:43.359: E/AndroidRuntime(24460):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
08-20 18:14:43.359: E/AndroidRuntime(24460):    at com.crm.DBHelper.getAllColleges(DBHelper.java:93)
```

**I have also noticed one thing, the copied `db` in emulator has `rwxrwx---` permission while the copied `db` in any device has `---rwxr-x` permission.**

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: where you opening the database to work with? I did not found any? may be you are accessing the db without opening it?

Comment: @naveedahmad `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();` In `getAllColleges()`

Comment: I have implemented this type code in one of my app, I will give you the tutorial link. follow that tutorial and you will find your way

Comment: An obvious question: It doesn't find the table named `colleges_list`. Do you have such table in your db?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yes I have checked the copied `db` using *SQLite Manager* and I saw all the tables inside it.

Comment: When I use a rawQuery (always), I use this syntax `SQLiteDatabase db  = getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);` instead of `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();`, which I assume being used by the "alternative way" of doing CRUD (I only use rawQuery & execSQL)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Unfortunately that too didn't worked :(

Comment: OK, the last thing that comes in my mind... WHERE are you putting the copied db? in WHICH PATH? app dbs should reside in `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I tried it at both locations i.e in `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db` and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/"+databaseName` but nothing changed

Comment: The second path is wrong.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein It isn't wrong. I can see my copied `db` at that path.

Comment: Yes, **you can** see it. **Android can't**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SQLiteAssetHelper` class to work with databases. It will help you to use your database without messing with file permissions.

*It's jar file can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-sqlite/android-sqlite-asset-helper.jar.zip). Download & import it in your project.*

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Db1.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public AssetsHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    public List<String> getAllColleges(){
        List<String> colleges = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM colleges_list ORDER BY Organization_Name";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                colleges.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning colleges
        return colleges;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the structure of your database?

If you have changes,  typically I uninstall the application prior to running the new version.  Running the new application does not remove the database, the uninstall however does.  You can also use the adb command 'adb uninstall yourpackagename'

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, I am not changing anything in database. Tried, still not working :(

Comment: The other thing you could try is changing the package name, that way your not dealing with anything related the original app.